LilyPond – mark chords style
How can I get LilyPond to have colored chords frames in a handwritten style?
I think this is a known style but I have not found any more info about it. Very cool, very jazzy!


I can’t help you with Lilypond but I wanted to mention there are 3 unmarked modulations, bars 3-5 up a major 3rd, bars 7-8 up a major 3rd and bar 15 back to 1 down a major 3rd.

I don't know about coloring but there is a handwritten-like font for LilyPond called lilyJAZZ:
https://github.com/OpenLilyPondFonts/lilyjazz
